# How to get the attempted url and header information?

Tags: ruby, rest, activeresource

I'm trying to connect to a web service endpoint, and I can't figure out how to debug this, my code is:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'active_resource'

class Project < ActiveResource::Base
  class << self
    attr_accessor :auth_token
  end

  def save
    prefix_options[:auth_token] = self.class.auth_token
    super
  end
end

Project.site = 'http://example.com:8080/api/v1'
Project.format = :json
Project.auth_token = 'aaa1112222333'
p = Project.new(:name => 'pizza time 1')
p.save
```

I am getting the following error:

```
gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@testing/gems/activeresource-3.2.9/lib/active_resource/connection.rb:130:in `handle_response': Failed.  Response code = 400.  Response message = Bad Request. (ActiveResource::BadRequest)
```

How can I output the exact url that was request, also if it was a POST or GET etc.?

Comment: Have you tried looking in the logs after a request is made? It will almost certainly show HTTP information.

Comment: This is not a ruby app, its talking to a java app.

Comment: I meant the active resource logs in your Ruby app. If you're not using Rails you will have to set up the logger yourself.